# Subtract 1 from var with a value of 100 each time you resize your browser smaller then 1600x1020

Tags: jquery, resize, browser-width

Is it possible to subtract 1 each time I were to resize my browser smaller then 1600x1020?

I know i need to start with a resize function but how do I go about store the new value where I can use in a new function?

```
 var resizeNum = 100;
 if (window.width() < 1600 && width.height()){
   resizeNum - 1
  }
```

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you clearly want to know when the browser is less than **1600x1020** I check both `height` and `width` below.  Also there are **4** ways of subtracting 1 from a variable:

```
//Sets number to -1 after any other use of the variable
var number = 0;
number--; //number = -1;

var number = 0;   
number-= 1; //number = -1;

var number = 0;   
number = number - 1; //number = -1;

//Sets number to -1 before any other use of the variable
var number = 0;   
--number; //number = -1;
```

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/D9a43/)

**JS:**

```
var resizeNum = 100;

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1600 || width.height() < 1020) {
        resizeNum--;
    }
    console.log(resizeNum);
});
```

Please remove the console.log when you are using this code it is just to prove it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
var resizeNum = 100;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(($(this).width() < 1600) && ($(this).height())) {
        resizeNum -= 1;
    }
});
```

This will call every time the window is resized. As it is resized, `resizeNum` will decrease by 1 each time.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this with using jquery
you need to add jquery file first.

```
// global variable
var resizeNum = 100;

// to check browser small than 1600 x 1020
var flag = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    decrementNum();
});

function decrementNum()
{
    var wW = $(window).width();
    var wH = $(window).height();

    if(wW < 1600 && wH < 1020 && flag == 0)
    {
        resizeNum--;
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if(wW > 1600 && wH > 1020)
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
     decrementNum();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  Either, you can declare the var at whatever your outermost layer is (certainly not in the function itself - possibly as far out as the page) or you can learn to use jQuery (which uses some rather nicely designed and fully unscoped variables).  Also, the line needs to be `resizeNum = resizeNum-1` rather than just `resizeNum -1`

Answer (score 0):

go through this *http://api.jquery.com/width*. it might be bit of help

use this

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport 
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

and also this

```
parseInt(resizeNum)-1
```